# Is it possible to have text inside a outlined box

Tags: jquery

I have some text in a text area and i will be changing this to a table

and one of the fields will hold the errors, i was wondering if it will be possible to have each text in that field to be outlined by a red box so the user can see more clearly that its an error

Thanks

Comment: I have not tried it as of yet im just asking to see if its possible

Comment: No, our technology is not advanced enough for text inside a box. Maybe in 20 years or so.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the css border property on whatever you're attempting to outline ?

`.clifford-the-big-red-box {
  border: 2px solid red;
}`

`$("#errors").addClass("clifford-the-big-red-box");`

That is, unless I've missed the point.....